# Appending new object created from different view controller performsegue

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, segue

First of all I want to thank anyone for taking the time to help me :)

Here is the structure used to create objects for my array.

```
struct cellData {
    let workoutName : String!
    let workoutSets : Int
    let workoutReps : Int
}
```

Then made an array out of cellData

```
var workoutArray = [cellData]()
```

basically in my MainScreen.swift I called a new variable that will hold the data passed from the performsegue function

```
var passedData = cellData(workoutName: "", workoutSets: 0, workoutReps: 0)
```

Then in my CreateWorkout.swift I specified what should happen before a segue. In this case I set the destination view controller and a new constant that will create a new object from the structure and set passedData equal to the value of UI elements in my view controller.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let workout = cellData(workoutName: workoutName.text, workoutSets: Int(setStepper.text!)!, workoutReps: Int(repStepper.text!)!)

    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! MainScreen
    destinationVC.passedData = workout

}
```

[Here is the app when I build the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQVQb.png)

Then I put Chest Press in my Text Field

Set the Set Stepper to 4

Set the Rep Stepper to 5

[It works right? Wrong!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE7xh.png)

I want to be able to append a new object every time I segue but instead, it just replaces the current object :(

Comment: I'm a bit confused - what are you dong with `cellData` afterwards? What do you expect it to be appended to?

Comment: @Michael I'm just using kinda like a class then using it to make an array out of the objects I make with it.

Comment: I think what you should do is make a datasource for your MainScreen and whenever you create a newDataCell , you should update the dataSource for the mainscreen and reload tableview in there

Comment: Are you using tableview in MainScreen.swift file

Comment: @user1000 yes I am, going to look into populating my table with a datasource

Comment: Ok good then you just have to decalre a dataSource(may be an array) and append every new dataCell to this dataSource,

Comment: @user1000 Awesome thank you so much!

Comment: @JafettPuga Glad I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a tableview there should be a datasource, so create a new datasource and everytime you create a new data cell just append it to this dataSource, this will ensure that you get a list of object in your MainScreen.